# How to use grep/egrep to count files in subdirectories containing a "String"

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

What I want to achieve is to get the count of all files in directory which contain a pattern `String`. And also not to count errors.

I have tried few commands but nothing seems to work this is what i have tried so far:

```sh
ls -l grep -cri "string" | wc -l

ls /path/ 2> /dev/null | grep -ci 'string' | wc -l

ls -l | grep -v ^l "string" | wc -l
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean "nothing seems to work"? What's wrong? Are you getting errors? Incorrect results?

Comment: the String count should be 3 but im getting thousands ?? that's maybe because i'm counting errors as well !! I have no Idea

Comment: Why would it be counting errors? You're not piping `stderr` to  `grep` or `wc -l`.

Comment: If you use `grep -c` you don't need to pipe to `wc -l`, since `grep` prints the count of matches by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-l` option to list just the filename when the contents match the pattern. Yse the `-r` option to recurse into subdirectories. Use the `-F` option to match the string exactly, rather than as a regular expression.

You need to tell it the name of the directory to recurse into; you can use `.` for the current directory.

Then pipe this to `wc -l`:

```
grep -rlF "string" . 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

Comment: I want to know how to use grep tho ?? i know this will work !!

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the files in a directory with "string" in the name you can do it like this:

```
ls -l | grep -c "string"
```

or if you want it to be case insensitive use -i

```
ls -l | grep -ci "string"
```

-c will print the count of matching lines.

Comment: There's no need for `-l`

Comment: but the string is not in the file name is in the file itself.

Comment: @zabdullh oh. the question was not clear.